# SQLite Update Listview Query Not Correct

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

I'm getting stuck on the query to perform an update I have the code for performing the update done correctly I'm just not to sure what the query to do this would be if someone could help that would be great. I'm passing through 3 variables and the 3 old variables as well and also the id. I know the query I've done is wrong just an attempt.

```
public void updateTable(String newDate, String newMethod, String newAmount, int id, String oldDate, String oldMethod, String oldAmount){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_INCOME + " SET " + COL2 + " " + COL3 + " " + COL4 + " = '" + newDate + newMethod + newAmount + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
        " AND " + COL2 + " " + COL3 + " " + COL4 + " = '" + oldDate + oldMethod + oldAmount + "'";
    db.execSQL(query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put("COL2", newDate);
values.put("COL3", newMethod );
values.put("COL4", newAmount );

long result = db.update("TABLE_INCOME", values, "COL1 = " + "'" + String.valueOf(id) +"'" , null);
Log.i(TAG, " update result : " + result);
```

don't use too many parameters. if your id is unique its enough. I hope it helps

Comment: `id` is not a string.

Comment: String.valueOf(id)

Comment: `"..."+id` actually works. The problem is that the `id` column in the database does not contain string values.

Comment: your id will be remain as integer. I just converted the id to String for querying purposes. see my edited answer

Comment: `"'" + String.valueOf(id) +"'"` results in an SQL string value.

Comment: If the `id` column does not have numeric affinity, the comparison will always fail.

Comment: then just check if the value of id is numeric before you update the database. see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java